# Frame position change using elisp not sticking

Tags: elisp, frames, linux

### Issue

I am able to change the frame position using `set-frame-position`. But the moment I use a function which uses `read-from-minibuffer`, the frame restores its position to where it was set using the mouse.

I am not sure if this is a bug because I have seen this issue probably since emacs 24.3 and am still seeing it in the latest build of emacs from its master branch.

### How to replicate this problem?

Here's a test function to help you replicate this problem.

```el
(defun my/alter-frame-pos ()
  (interactive)
  (set-frame-position nil 100 100)) ; pixels x y from upper left
```

1. Launch `emacs -Q`.
2. Eval the above function in the *scratch* buffer.
3. Position the frame to any random location **using** the mouse
4. `M-x my/alter-frame-pos`. You should see the frame jump to (100,100) pixel location.
5. `M-x find-file` or `C-x C-f` (this is one of the functions that uses `read-from-minibuffer`)
6. The frame will jump back to wherever you set it using the mouse!

So basically my frame altering elisp snippet is useless as I have to use the mouse to make the position stick.

I tried edebug but I couldn't go further as `read-from-minibuffer` is in C and I can't figure out how mouse based frame dragging sets its position.

### Solution attempt 1

I tried using Drew's suggestion but the problem still persists.

```el
(defun my/alter-frame-pos ()
  (interactive)
  (set-frame-parameter nil 'user-position t)
  (set-frame-position nil 100 100)) ; pixels x y from upper left
```

*As of writing this question, I was using emacs 25 built on April 16 2015 on RHEL 5.10, GTK+ version 2.10.4, Gnome 2.16.0.*

### Questions

1. Are you able to replicate this issue?

   > As Drew reported, this issue is not replicated on Windows. So the problem could be specific to Linux or the flavor of Linux I am using (default Gnome that came with RHEL 5.10).
2. <s>If so, is there a right way of setting the frame position using elisp?</s>
3. Should this be filed as a bug report?

   > **debbugs [#20361](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20361)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will consider this as a system-specific issue.

**I saw this issue on RHEL 5. But I don't see this anymore on RHEL 6.**

With the emacs built from the git master branch today, `M-x emacs-version` returns,

> GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.23) of 2015-09-14

`lsb_release -a` returns,

> LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-ia32:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-ia32:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-ia32:printing-4.0-noarch
>   Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseWorkstation
>   Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.6 (Santiago)
>   Release:        6.6
>   Codename:       Santiago

Answer (score 0):

See frame parameter `user-position`, and the Elisp manual, node [`Positional Parameters`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Position-Parameters.html).

Set parameter `user-position` to non-`nil`, to tell your window manager that the position you have moved the frame to is, in effect, a user-defined position.  This suggests to the window manager not to mess with it further.

And no, I don't see that problem using your recipe. But I am using MS Windows, and the behavior for this kind of thing can be window manager-specific.

And no, this should not be filed as a bug report, I think.  Whether programmatic setting of frame parameters should be considered by the window manager as having been set by the user is a choice that depends on the context.

It is the raison d'etre for parameter `user-position`. In some cases you do not want programmatic changes to override the position that a user might have established. In your example, suppose that, for some context, you do *not* want the program to override the position the user chose with the mouse.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how to set the `user-position` parameter? It seems like I need to set that when creating a frame? Because `set-frame-position` does not have that argument.

Comment: `C-h f set-frame-parameter` -- `(set-frame-parameter nil 'user-position t)`. The most general function for modifying frame parameters is `modify-frame-parameters`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but that did not help.

Comment: In that case, perhaps someone else has an explanation or suggestion. You can try reporting that as a bug, but I doubt that it will be considered such. In any case, specify your platform (window manager). Emacs cannot oblige the window manager to respect a frame position that Emacs tries to set.

Comment: For clarification, the `set-frame-position` is successfully able to change the frame position regardless of the `user-position` parameter value. But the moment I use `C-x C-f`, the position resets to where I had set the frame using the mouse. It's as if the position referenced by the C function `read-from-minibuffer` gets updated only when I use mouse to move the frame, but not when I use the `set-frame-position` function.

Comment: I understand (and understood). You can try to find out whether it is Emacs (e.g. `read-from-minibuffer`) that is requesting that the frame move or it is the window manager that is moving the frame as it sees fit. You can go ahead and report the problem (`M-x report-emacs-bug`), to get others to take a look. If someone can repro it then they might be able to help. On my platform the recipe given does not repro the problem.